# CircleCI + React Native + Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, circleci, fastlane

I have an app running fine with React Native 0.57.7 on CircleCI on Xcode 9.
But we need to bump up Xcode version to 10.1.0.

But when I switch it, Ci stops to work, even with enabling legacy system (`-UseNewBuildSystem=NO` or `-UseModernBuildSystem=0` being passed to Fastlane's `build_ios_app`), I get "Myapp.app/main.jsbundle does not exist" error.

```
▸ + echo 'error: File /Users/distiller/project/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Myapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Myapp.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with'
▸ error: File /Users/distiller/project/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Myapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Myapp.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with
▸ + echo 'React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues'
▸ React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues
```

Comment: It's written: "_please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues_"

Comment: I don't know if its a bug yet. I'm trying to see if anyone had it before first. Thx

Comment: Then you seem poor at searching: it's already findable on both [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+main.jsbundle+does+not+exist) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=main.jsbundle+does+not+exist).

Comment: thank you, but that was the first thing that I did!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some hours spent just to figure out what was going on with it, I found out the issue: the build is failing silently because the docker image for Xcode 10.1.0 on CircleCI is missing some dependencies needed to build the app by React Native.

The error was just saying “main.jsbundle does not exist”. It happens when xcode runs `react-native-cli bundle` from `react-native-xcode.sh` file. And it doesn't tell the root cause for the error: `watchman` is missing in the docker image used by this Xcode version.

Why those images don’t have the same installed packages? I don’t know. I was only expecting the same installed packages between the images.

Adding `brew install watchman` makes the CI pass again:

```
- run:
    name: "Install React Native dependencies"
    command: |
      brew update
      brew install watchman
```

I wish `react-native-xcode.sh` could return the root error instead of just `main.jsbundle does not exist`

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved it for me. How did you find out?

Comment: I've tried many things. But one that gave that guided me into this direction was: I've added a ci job to run `react-native bundle` (what is run internally by react-native-xcode.sh) and that presented an error saying that watchman was not found.

Comment: MY MAN. You are a life saver

Comment: Thank you so much!  Fixed my circleci build

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me to find the actual issue in bundle fail.